# Custom submit button text

Tags: forms

I have a  classic contact form. I can add for example some custom placeholder like this :

```
function my_theme_form_contact_message_about_your_project_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
    // placeholder
    $form['field_contact_name']['widget'][0]['value']['#placeholder'] = t('Saisir votre nom');

}
```

It works very well and I can also easily modify wrapper, name, etc.

But for a reason I can’t understand, I am not able to modify the text of the submit button.

Here is what I’ve tried among a lot of things and I think it should be the right thing (as seen on other answers) :

```
$form['actions']['submit']['#value'] = 'hello world!';
```

Here is the html of the button :

```
<button data-drupal-selector="edit-submit" class="button button--primary js-form-submit form-submit btn-primary btn" type="submit" id="edit-submit" name="op" value="Envoyer">Envoyer</button>
```

I use a custom theme based on Bootstrap theme.

Of course, I can do it with jQuery :

```
$('#edit-submit').text('lorem ipsum');
```

But I would like to know how to do it the Drupal way.

**EDIT** :

The solution is :

```
form['actions']['submit']['#value'] = 'hello world!';
```

It works on a clean Drupal install but not on the website I am currently working on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do you know why it is not working ?

Because it seems to me that you're playing the guessing game.

How about installing the [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) and adding `kint($form)` to inspect the `$form` array?

You will see its

```
$form['actions']['submit']['#value'] = t('Post Comments');
```

Comment: Before asking, I've already tried `$form['actions']['submit']['#value'] = t('Post Comments');` (as seen on other answer) and it didn't work. I should have mentioned this in my question. I will install Devel.

Comment: Hello you're right. I've already tested your solution before asking. Since, it didn't work, I asked here form more information. So, I've tried on a clean Drupal install and it works. It doesn't work on the website I am currently working on for some specific reason I need to find (I didn't create this web site, only creating a new theme).

Comment: I've found the issue on the website : there is a CustomController where I found code about forms and it was overriding my code : `$build['contact_form']['actions']['submit']['#value'] = 'lorem ipsum';` Sorry to have disturbed you, not easy to work on a website you don't know.